# read results data from file, load it, compare it , and print the display

Tags: c++

C++ :A load function that loads competition results from a given text file, analysis each competition result by modify the two teams’ information as following:
 o If a team is not exists in the Team array, add the team in the Team array. 
o If the team already exists,
 modify the team’s data by
Increase the total win by one if the team won the competition; 
Increase the total loss by one if the team lost;
Add the score that the team has got to the total score for;
Add the score that opponent team has got to the total score against.

• A sort function that sorts the teams in the descending order according to the total win. If the total win times are the same, compare the total loss time, the less the better. If the total win and total loss times are the same, compare the differences of total score for and total score against, the bigger the better. The sorting algorithm is up to you.

• A print function print out the teams’ records to screen.

###############OUTPUT MUST BE LIKE THIS

```
Input a basketball competition results' file name: results.txt
Shellharbour      10 0 471 100
Raptors           6 5 227 257
Bobcats           6 5 178 225
Spurs             6 6 275 270
MTSO Warriors     5 7 234 273
Mavericks         1 11 159 419
```

**and the data in text file is :- **

```
Shellharbour:MTSO Warriors
50:21
Spurs:Bobcats
23:28
Raptors:Mavericks
37:12
Spurs:MTSO Warriors
20:12
Mavericks:Bobcats
20:26
Raptors:MTSO Warriors
16:26
Raptors:Shellharbour
9:50
Spurs:Mavericks
24:15
Bobcats:MTSO Warriors
21:12
Spurs:MTSO Warriors
17:26
Mavericks:Shellharbour
10:64
Raptors:Mavericks
32:14
Bobcats:Spurs
2:20
Mavericks:MTSO Warriors
8:48
Shellharbour:Bobcats
44:6
Raptors:Spurs
27:17
Mavericks:Bobcats
8:26
MTSO Warriors:Raptors
16:26
Spurs:Shellharbour
14:39
Mavericks:Spurs
20:53
Raptors:Shellharbour
9:30
MTSO Warriors:Bobcats
18:13
Raptors:Bobcats
16:13
Shellharbour:Mavericks
58:5
MTSO Warriors:Spurs
11:18
Mavericks:Raptors
18:22
Bobcats:Spurs
22:18
MTSO Warriors:Shellharbour
5:61
Spurs:Raptors
34:26
Mavericks:MTSO Warriors
16:12
Shellharbour:Bobcats
33:4
Bobcats:Mavericks
17:13
MTSO Warriors:Raptors
27:7
Shellharbour:Spurs
42:17
```

Comment: We don't do your homework for free.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: i have tried lots but never able to run the code.

Comment: Someone may solve it for fun, but what if your teacher searches the web?

Comment: i am not looking for the exact answer and make copy paste and get marks .

Comment: just want to know ways like till how to get those team and score and store it in array the rest i can do it

Comment: try to solve it, post what you have and say why it doesn't work.

Comment: i am trying to read those contents from file and store it on different array like team1 for first team team2 for second team and team1score and team2score for respective teams. i have done this so far but having lots of confusing can somebody help me out. thanks in advance.

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 string *team1,*team2,*score1,*score2,s;
 int count=0;
 string str;
 fstream inputfile("results.txt");
 if(!inputfile)
 {
  cout<<"No input File"<<endl;
 }
 while(getline(inputfile,s))
 {
  if(s.length()!=0)
  {
   ++count;
  }
  
 }
 count=count/2;
 team1=new string[count];
 team2=new string[count];
 score1=new string[count];
 score2=new string[count];
 inputfile.close();
 fstream filename("results.txt");
 for(int i=0;i<count;)
 {

Comment: if(i%2==0)
   {
    while(getline(filename,str));
    istringstream stream(str);
    getline(stream,team1[i],':');
    getline(stream,team2[i],':');
    //cout<<"team 1 = \t"<<team1<<" VS "<<"team 2 = \t"<<team2<<endl;
   }
   else if(i%2!=0)
   {
    while(getline(filename,str));
    istringstream stream(str);
    getline(stream,score1[i],':');
    getline(stream,score2[i],':');
    //cout<<"team1score = \t"<<score1<<" VS "<<"team2score = \t"<<score2<<endl;  }i++;
 }
 for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
 {cout<<team1[i]<<" Vs "<<team2[i]<<endl;
  cout<<score1[i]<<" Vs "<<score2[i]<<endl;
 }return 0;
}

Comment: To let someone know about your comment add @ followed by user name. Don't post code in comments. Delete the posts and add the code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution depends on what you're allowed to use. Since you said that you can use `std`, here are some observations that may help you:

Define a `result` structure to hold the name of the two teams and scores. Add a `read` method:

```
struct result_type
{

  std::string n1, n2;
  int s1, s2;

  std::istream& read( std::istream& is )
  {
    // use getline...
    return is;
  }

};
```

I see five columns in your output sample. Each column must be a field in a structure. Define a class to store those columns. Add an `update` method and a `write` one:

```
struct team_type
{
  std::string name;
  int total_win;
  // more fields...

  void update( result_type& r )
  {
    // ...
  }

  std::ostream& write( std::ostream& os )
  {
    os << name;
    // ...
    return os;
  }

};
```

The teams must be stored in a `Team Name to Team Info map` (you should read about `std::map`, otherwise you will not understand what’s happening).

```
typedef std::map< std::string, team_type > team_name_to_team_type;
```

Read the results and update the teams stored in the above map:

```
ifstream is( "input.txt" );
if ( !is )
  return -1;

team_name_to_team_type teams;
result_type r;
while ( r.read( is ) )
{
  teams[r.n1].update( r );
  teams[r.n2].update( r );
}
```

After you’re done with the reading you should store the result in a `Total Win to Team Info multimap` (std maps and multimaps are self-sorting):

```
typedef std::multimap< int, team_type > total_win_to_team_type;

total_win_to_team_type sorted_teams;
for ( team_name_to_team_type::const_iterator i = teams.begin(); i != teams.end(); ++i )
  sorted_teams[i->second.total_win] = *i;
```

And display it:

```
for ( total_win_to_team_type::const_iterator i = sorted_teams.begin(); i != sorted_teams.end(); ++i )
  i->second.write( std::cout );
```

Comment: i just want to store that teams and their score in different arrays like

Comment: You may use arrays instead of maps, but you will need additional functions: search by team's name, for instance.